# Using IDs in LESS

Tags: css, less

I've started using LESS recently and it's really convenient, and I have a question: as it's really convenient to place element inside the brackets to clarify the style structure, in .CSS file that's being generated I end up seeing things like this:

```
#second-block .side-menu #category .content{...}
```

Is this okay to have **id** elements inside other **id** elements, even though I use LESS?

Comment: Just make sure that you won't land with something like [this](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2365) or [this](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2551). I.e. if it's supposed to be `#category .content` selector, do not make it `#second-block .side-menu #category .content` (i.e. the other observation is "Nesting for the sake of nesting is evil"). Though technically all this makes your Q to be quite offtopic as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: Don't duplicate ID's also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's ok to have **id** element inside other **id** elements.

The generated .css will work.

Personally, I like to use as few **id** elements in my code as possible. The reasoning behind this, is how some browsers don't like it when you have multiple instances of the same **id** on the page. I find that using **classes** is more flexible.

Here's a relevant stack overflow question that mentions on ids vs. classes:

[Is there any pros and cons if i use always CSS Class instead CSS ID for everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878810/is-there-any-pros-and-cons-if-i-use-always-css-class-instead-css-id-for-everythi)