# Show/hide button depending on the heigth of his hidden parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a bit new to programming and this is a complicated problem for me.

I am building a site and I am making it fully responsive (http://www.metagame.gg/champions/azir)

I want to display a "*Read more*" button if the content of a div is higher than 80px

This is an example:
[image: Divs with different height]
As we can see, the middle Div doesn't display the "*Read more*" button because there isn't more content to show.

To do this, I use this jquery code, where .expandClicker is the class of the button.

```
jQuery('.expandClicker').each(function(){
  if ( jQuery(this).parent().height() < 80 ) {
    jQuery(this).css({'display':'none'});
  }
});
```

This works great, however, **it can't be used when the viewport is smaller than 980px** because the page changes and **the parent becomes a hidden div**. So the jquery code detects that the parent div height is 0px even tho it isn't, so the "*Read more*" button is never displayed.

The page for screens smaller than 980px:
[image: minus 980px]

Once the div is expanded, the "*Read more*" buttons don't appear because the parent div height was 0px.
[image: expanded]

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I would suggest this: For mobile view do NOT show ever "read more" and let content flow, do not limit the height. Another note: you mixed/switched IDs and classes for each id=sectionTitle, id must be unique on the page.

Comment: Thank you, I think that it is a very good idea. Any downside on non unique IDs?

Answer (score 0):

**Any downside on non unique IDs?** Yes!!...

[jakeboxer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96514/jakeboxer)
have answerd lt [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1878893/6221400).