# Callout not closing when not hovered

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a callout as follows. As you can see, the callout not being hidden when I hover out from the `i` icon. Do I use the wrong event? I tried switching `mouseover` and `mouseleave` but the callout looks blinking.

Any help appreciated! :)

```js
$(".text-with-tooltip i").hover(function() {
  $(".callout-tooltip").show();
});
```

```css
.text-with-tooltip {
  font-size: 13px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.text-with-tooltip i {
  margin-left: 4px; 
  font-size: 11px;
}

.callout.callout-tooltip {
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.callout.callout-tooltip {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 28%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -28%);
  display: none;
}

.callout.callout-tooltip::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 0.8em solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
}

.callout.callout-tooltip.top::before {
  left: 45%;
  bottom: -20px;
  border-top: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.tooltip-wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="tooltip-wrapper">
  <div class="text-with-tooltip">Manual<i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></div>
</div>

<div class="callout top callout-tooltip">You must enter the request number every time you add new entry on Reimbursement Entry</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: **1.** You hover over the icon. `hover` is triggered. **2.** The popup appears *in front of the icon*. **3.** Because the icon is blocked, `hover` is interrupted and the popup disappears. **4.** The icon is no longer covered. **Rinse and repeat.**.   This all happens in the span of milliseconds, thus your flashing/flickering. Simply repositioning the tooltip so that it doesn't cover your `i` icon should solve the problem (assuming you add the second `mouseout` parameter of `.hover(...)` back in).

Comment: @TylerRoper thank you for your explanation. I keep my function and try repositioning the callout, but it still doesn't work..

Comment: Can you edit your question to include that example instead? We'd rather have code that reproduces the issue than code without, as it's much easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add this to your JS:

```
$(".text-with-tooltip i").mouseleave(function() {
  $(".callout-tooltip").hide();
});
```

You will be good.

Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/rdenu53a/

Comment: I would test that before being so sure - if you make your answer a snippet with OPs code, this causes the same flickering that OP described.

Comment: @TylerRoper well... I tried pairing `mousover` and `mouseleave` since I thought they were commonly paired. I don't know that I can pair `hover` and `mouseleave` tho ;) ;)

Comment: @Rosiana `hover` is a shorthand container for `mouseover` and `mouseleave` - this means that `hover` and `mouseover` are *identical*. If you edit the snippet in your question and add this to it, it will flicker all the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use the function with an ID instead of the CSS class, you can try this.

```
$("#yourID").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer').attr('title', 'This is a hover text.');
}, function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','auto');
});
```

I would recommend using an ID instead of a class because IDs have a [higher importance level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878810/is-there-any-pros-and-cons-if-i-use-always-css-class-instead-css-id-for-everythi) and this might save you some headache down the road if you have a bunch of elements on the page with the same class that you want to treat differently.

Comment: This does not solve any of OPs issues. OP has obviously gone through a few lengths to have a custom-styled tooltip, I'd imagine this isn't a useful alternative.