# Disadvantage of using only classes in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Is there any negative to using only classes in HTML as opposed to ids and classes? (meaning that even if an element occurs once, it is still given a class rather than an id)

**EDIT** - How severe is the performance hit when using JavaScript with classes as opposed to ids?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disregarding speed and compatibility, why not use only classes and never use IDs in HTML/CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420809/disregarding-speed-and-compatibility-why-not-use-only-classes-and-never-use-ids)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### JavaScript

For JavaScript, IDs provide a fast and deterministic way to select one and only one element. Selection by class (e.g. using a library like jQuery) can be useful e.g. "do this to all elements with class name XYZ".

### Performance

> How severe is the performance hit when using JavaScript with classes
>   as opposed to ids?

**Try it and see:** http://jsperf.com/class-versus-id. In Chrome, I'm seeing varying differences (5%-40% slower to use class name). Note that `getElementsByClassName` is not universally supported (John Resig has a [comparison of custom implmentations](http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/)).

### CSS

From a CSS perspective I use IDs sparingly and only when I know there will ever be one match (since IDs must be unique).

However, I think the question neglects one of the most important abilities of CSS: the ability to use [structural selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors). Without these selectors combined with classes (and sometimes IDs), you risk having much more brittle and verbose CSS.

Complex selectors can also be extremely useful in JavaScript when implemented in an engine like [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/).

In other words, every element should probably not have an ID and/or class explicitly assigned to it.

Consider:

```
.foo .bar1 { }
.foo .bar2 { }
#bar3 { }
```

Versus:

```
.foo > SECTION { }
.foo > SECTION + SECTION { }
.foo:last-child { }

SECTION H2 { }
P + P { margin-top: 1em; }
/* etc */
```

In the first example, everything must be explicitly ID'd or have a class stated. The second examples rely more on document structure.

Ultimately the goal should be maintainable code first while achieving the cleanest markup possible.

Comment: In Firefox 10.0.2 I'm getting 60%-70% slower results for `getElementsByClassName()` alone. Often `getElementsByClassName()` is used only as a starting point to navigate to a specific element, in that case I think we would see even worse results.

Comment: @TelmoMarques - I just updated my post. I'm seeing up to 40% slower in Chrome (though it really varies). Also agreed on the performance hit when using more complex selectors in JS; the question is really whether it matters or not? I think in most implementations clean code and maintainability would be more important.

Comment: It's important to look at the performance of id's when combined with other selectors to get a more complete picture. Their advantage mostly falls away in those scenarios.

Comment: This is a very thorough answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the hooks for javascript, id's aren't necessary. Unlike id's, classes are reusable and you'll find [some who advocate](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/) avoiding using id's for css altogether (I avoid it myself.) You'll find [CSSLint](http://csslint.net/) suggests you avoid them too. There isn't widespread agreement on that yet, so you should consider both sides of that particular argument.

Comment: You don't NEED IDs for JS, but it tends to be more performant to use them. IDs also have a higher specificity in CSS, so can be used as a 'hook' in CSS as well.

Comment: It's only more performant if they're used in isolation. As soon as other selectors are included with them they lose their performance gain because css rules are processed from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

There is no disadvantage to not using IDs, unless you have the need to specifically refer to a single element.

Classes are also optional but allow you to refer to multiple elements at once.

That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

---

Answer (score 0):

No real problem.
Rather i would say the other way around is wrong, giving a single class alone and no ID's to many different elements. If you want to access a single element alone from all the elements with that class, then you would run into trouble

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of an ID is that in CSS it's more specific than a class, so you can leverage that if need be and in JavaScript it's quicker to access a DOM element by ID than by class.

As to whether or not it's a disadvantage to not use IDs in your situation would be dependent on if the above are issues or not.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from experience, I'd have to say that not using IDs can have some disadvantages. Particularly when trying to integrate some JavaScript you made with any rather complex web application (because of no better alternative), or when parsing complete web pages, or even when developing JavaScript for your own website.

If you ever tried any of the above then maybe you've already found yourself wishing every major element had an ID, because:

- An ID provides direct access to the element, instead of having to navigate through the DOM tree to get to the element you want.
- If the structure of the document changes, but IDs remain the same, you probably won't have to fix anything.

Just to name a couple of reasons, I'm sure more could be found.

I'd have to say that a proper balanced use of both IDs and classes is the way to go. If you don't want to use IDs in CSS, then don't. But that doesn't prevent you from using IDs if you, or others, can take advantage from them.