# Is it possible to have multiple ID selectors in CSS

Tags: html, css

Is this correct and does it work correctly across browsers?

```
<div id="test">
  Some stuff
    <div id="anotherTest">
      More stuff
    </div>
  Even more stuff
</div>
```

CSS...

```
#test #anotherTest {
  color:red;
}
```

Only "More stuff" would be in red.

I know I could use classes and there are several different ways to achieve this but basically I'm asking about selecting an element with CSS via several IDs?

Thanks.

Comment: in your example if you set #test to red, #anotherTest will be red too by inherit of parent, if there is no other css that change it.

Comment: Sure, you can do that, but it is meaningless, since there can only be one `#anotherTest` element in your document.

Comment: Sure that will work, just make sure that the `id` is only used *once per page*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, it works cross browser, and what you wrote is correct. Only "More stuff" will be in red.

But it is not recommended to use ID's for styling.
A nice reference to read more about this can be found [here](http://csswizardry.com/2012/11/code-smells-in-css/#ids). The entire article is a great read by the way, if you want to learn more about writing good CSS!

The most important part of it, concerning IDs is:

- IDs can never be used more than once in a page.
- Classes can exist only once, or a million times in a page.
- IDs can often have their traits abstracted out into many reusable classes.
- An ID is infinitely more specific than a class.
- This means no amount of chained classes can override an ID.

Answer (score 5):

Yes this approach is possible

```
#test #anotherTest {
  color:red;
}
```

It selects the element with `id` `anotherTest` which has the `ancestor` with `id` `test`

Please [READ](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/) this

Comment: *An ancestor* with id "test", not the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.

If you want both `#anotherTest` and `#test` to be red, add a comma.

```
#test, #anotherTest {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to style a web page using CSS, but it seems your question is not only related to style but rather even on selectors. Check out the below w3school link about CSS Selectors

> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

and an excellent demo of CSS Selectors in action

> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.asp?selector=.intro

And it supports across all popular browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use classes always, i.e:

```
<div class="test">
  Some stuff
    <div class="anotherTest">
      More stuff
    </div>
    <div class="andAnotherTest">
      Even More stuff
    </div>
  Even more stuff
</div>
```

and then in css:

```
.test .anotherTest {
   color: red;
}

.test .andAnotherTest {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Why always use classes ? When you only need one you use id

Comment: Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298607/css-best-practice-about-id-and-class), you should only use id's for an element uniqueness, otherwise you should use classes.

Comment: That's what I said ... Anyways this wasn't the issue here