# jQuery click function won't work on my div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having snow effect javascript. Wanted to make each flake clickable but i don't know what i am doing wrong here...

```
$('#flake').click(function(e) {  
  alert("Test");
});
```

Here is the code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBVJjB
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Marko! The problem is, you are using an `id` instead of a `class`. You should start learning the fundamental things about HTML, classes, ids… One good read is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298607/css-best-practice-about-id-and-class

Comment: Please put your code in the question rather than linking.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: http://codepen.io/Ajay-Mathur/pen/mOXVov

Answer (score 5):

There are several issues.

- unique ids
- event delegation

The flakes should have their *own* unique selector, which in this situation would probably be a class. `<div class="flake">`. ids should be unique, and in your codepen they are not.

The click event that you have is tied to only the *one* div with id flake that is present in the DOM at the time of assignment, which due to delay, may be none. Instead the event should be delegated to all flakes, preferably with the class selector described above

```
$("body").on("click",".flake",function(e){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of issues with your approach/ code.

1. HTML document should have unique ID, therefore replace your id with class.
2. The elements are dynamically added to the DOM and they don't exist at the time the script is executed therefore attach the event to document and delegate them to your flake class.

Working Snippet:

```js
/**
 * jquery.snow - jQuery Snow Effect Plugin
 *
 * Available under MIT licence
 *
 * @version 1 (21. Jan 2012)
 * @author Ivan Lazarevic
 * @requires jQuery
 * @see http://workshop.rs
 *
 * @params minSize - min size of snowflake, 10 by default
 * @params maxSize - max size of snowflake, 20 by default
 * @params newOn - frequency in ms of appearing of new snowflake, 500 by default
 * @params flakeColor - color of snowflake, #FFFFFF by default
 * @example $.fn.snow({ maxSize: 200, newOn: 1000 });
 */
(function($) {

  $.fn.snow = function(options) {

    var $flake = $('<div class="flake" />').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': '-50px'
      }).html('&#10052;'),
      documentHeight = $(document).height(),
      documentWidth = $(document).width(),
      defaults = {
        minSize: 10,
        maxSize: 20,
        newOn: 500,
        flakeColor: "#FFFFFF"
      },
      options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);


    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      var startPositionLeft = Math.random() * documentWidth - 100,
        startOpacity = 0.5 + Math.random(),
        sizeFlake = options.minSize + Math.random() * options.maxSize,
        endPositionTop = documentHeight - 40,
        endPositionLeft = startPositionLeft - 100 + Math.random() * 200,
        durationFall = documentHeight * 10 + Math.random() * 5000;
      $flake
        .clone()
        .appendTo('body')
        .css({
          left: startPositionLeft,
          opacity: startOpacity,
          'font-size': sizeFlake,
          color: options.flakeColor
        })
        .animate({
            top: endPositionTop,
            left: endPositionLeft,
            opacity: 0.2
          },
          durationFall,
          'linear',
          function() {
            $(this).remove()
          }
        );
    }, options.newOn);

  };

})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.snow();
  });
</script>
<script>
  $(document).on("click", '.flake', function(e) {
    alert("Test");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `id` attribute should be unique across elements in the document.
2. The `$('#flake').click(...` code runs before the `<div id="flake">` elements were added to the page, so the `click` event was not attached to them. You can fix this by using `$(document).on('click', '#flake', function() {... });`

Here is the fix to your code:

```js
/**
 * jquery.snow - jQuery Snow Effect Plugin
 *
 * Available under MIT licence
 *
 * @version 1 (21. Jan 2012)
 * @author Ivan Lazarevic
 * @requires jQuery
 * @see http://workshop.rs
 *
 * @params minSize - min size of snowflake, 10 by default
 * @params maxSize - max size of snowflake, 20 by default
 * @params newOn - frequency in ms of appearing of new snowflake, 500 by default
 * @params flakeColor - color of snowflake, #FFFFFF by default
 * @example $.fn.snow({ maxSize: 200, newOn: 1000 });
 */
(function($){
  $.fn.snow = function(options){

    var $flake    = $('<div class="flake" />').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '-50px'}).html('&#10052;'),
        documentHeight  = $(document).height(),
        documentWidth = $(document).width(),
        defaults  = {
          minSize  : 10,
          maxSize  : 20,
          newOn  : 500,
          flakeColor : "#FFFFFF"
        },
        options   = $.extend({}, defaults, options);


    var interval  = setInterval( function(){
      var startPositionLeft  = Math.random() * documentWidth - 100,
          startOpacity  = 0.5 + Math.random(),
          sizeFlake   = options.minSize + Math.random() * options.maxSize,
          endPositionTop  = documentHeight - 40,
          endPositionLeft  = startPositionLeft - 100 + Math.random() * 200,
          durationFall  = documentHeight * 10 + Math.random() * 5000;
      $flake
      .clone()
      .appendTo('body')
      .css(
        {
          left: startPositionLeft,
          opacity: startOpacity,
          'font-size': sizeFlake,
          color: options.flakeColor
        }
      )
      .animate(
        {
          top: endPositionTop,
          left: endPositionLeft,
          opacity: 0.2
        },
        durationFall,
        'linear',
        function() {
          $(this).remove()
        }
      );
    }, options.newOn);

  };

})(jQuery);

$(function(){
  $.fn.snow();
  $(document).on("click", '.flake',function() {  
    alert("Test");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```